# C# listView Control LargeIcon View without columns / without subitems: How to align Item Text in MiddleCenter?

Tags: c#, listview, controls, listviewitem, text-alignment

I have a System.Windows.Forms ListView Control in LargeIcon View and the text of the elements is displayed weirdly left-aligned. I found so far no property for the ListView Control to align the text of the ListViewItems middle or middlecenter. I have no columns in my ListView and no subitems
to manage this through the header property (because of the LargeIcon View).

How would I allow the user to move a ListViewItem to another position within my ListView?
Somehow all the items seem to be auto-snapped, doesn't matter if I use AutoArrange or not.
If I don't use AutoArrange the ListViewItems are just aligned left and only the very 
left border of the ListView is being used for displaying the items and a long vertical scrollbar appears (not intended). However in both cases the user seems not to be able to move a LargeIcon Item
to another position within the ListView. All Items are fixed to their positions. Any ideas on how to change this behaviour?